# Javascript If between appendChild and replaceChild not working

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically generating a table and after that I want to append it as a child to a div. The problem is every time i regenerate the table it gets appended in the same div without the old table removed.

```
if(context.children.length == 0){
    context.appendChild(table);
}else{
    context.replaceChild(table);
}
```

I tried with checking if the child already exists and if it does i replace it with the new element.
But I get the error `The argument is not optional` and I don't know how to do it otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: `replaceChild` method should have 2 args .... new and old child

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the stupid question. As I have only one child I have not thought about this.

Comment: Can you make a normal answer that I can mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how replaceChild() works, You should, `paremtElement.replaceChild(new element, element to be replaced)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the second argument as the child to be replaced in [`Node#replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) method.

```
if(context.children.length == 0){
    context.appendChild(table);
}else{
    context.replaceChild(table, context.children[0]);
}
```